# Can't get the total value of 2 children in Firebase database - Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a method that will upload an app order. You can get the price from database (harga) and amount from the user, but I can't get the total from that. It always gets value as 0.

So here's my code:

```java
public void uploadImg() {
    if (FilePathUri != null) {
        progressDialog.setTitle("Process...");
        progressDialog.show();
        StorageReference storageReference2 = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + GetFileExtension(FilePathUri));
        
        storageReference2.putFile(FilePathUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                final String ukuran = UkuranPasFoto.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
                final int jumlah = Integer.parseInt(JumlahPasFoto.getText().toString().trim());
                final String catatan = inputCatatan.getText().toString().trim();
                final int status = 0;

                databaseHarga.child("harga").child("pasFoto").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        int harga = dataSnapshot.child(ukuran).getValue(Integer.class);

                        int total = harga*jumlah;

                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sucess !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        PesanPasFoto ImageUploadInfo = new PesanPasFoto(uid, ukuran, jumlah, catatan, total, status, taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri().toString());
                        String ImageUploadId = database.push().getKey();
                        database.child(ImageUploadId).setValue(ImageUploadInfo);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(PasFotoActivity.this,"Please Select Image or Fill the blank",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

here's my database

[image]

As you can see that "total" value is always 0
and there's nothing wrong in logcat

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: Check what is the value of total before pushing it to the database. If it is 0, check the value of harga and jumlah. You can use log to print values.